# Lombok: Equals for string instance variables in subclass

Tags: java, string, equals, lombok

I recently stumbled across [`Lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/) and wanted to test it, when I ran into this slight problem.

Suppose I have

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Name extends AbstractName {

    @NonNull
    private String firstname;

    @NonNull
    private String lastname;

}
```

where `AbstractName` is an empty abstract class. I want to test the `equals` method with

```
@Test
public void testEquals() {
    Name instance1 = new Name("Vorname","Nachname");
    Name instance2 = new Name("Vorname","Nachname");
    boolean expResult = true;
    boolean result = instance1.equals(instance2);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

As you can see, I would expect the two instances of `Name` to be equal. In case you add

```
System.out.println(instance1.getFirstname().equals(instance2.getFirstname()));
System.out.println(instance1.getLastname().equals(instance2.getLastname()));
```

one gets

```
true
true
```

So, why does the test fail? Is it a `hashCode()` problem due to the inheritence of `AbstractName`? How can I fix that?

BTW, it does not fail, if `Name` is a standalone class and not a subclass of `AbstractName`.

---

### Vanilla Java

This is code created by `Lombok`

```
@java.lang.Override
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
@lombok.Generated
public boolean equals(final java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Name)) return false;
    final Name other = (Name) o;
    if (!other.canEqual((java.lang.Object) this)) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    final java.lang.Object this$firstname = this.getFirstname();
    final java.lang.Object other$firstname = other.getFirstname();
    if (this$firstname == null ? other$firstname != null : !this$firstname.equals(other$firstname)) return false;
    final java.lang.Object this$lastname = this.getLastname();
    final java.lang.Object other$lastname = other.getLastname();
    if (this$lastname == null ? other$lastname != null : !this$lastname.equals(other$lastname)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can not reproduce. For me, `equals` returns `true`. Empty `AbstractName` does not make a difference. Did not use `assertEquals` but check the result directly, though.

Comment: I forgot something in the initial question and editted it. Did you use the current version of the question?

Comment: I also can't reproduce here, returns true for me. What's the content of the `AbstractName`? As far as I know, Lombok will not call the super equals/haschcode from the super class by default, but I asked to understand the whole scenario

Comment: See [@EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) which is included when using @Data.  You'll probably want to suppress calling super.equals.

Comment: Ah , I see. I had `lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = call` in my `lombok.config`. I took that out and added `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)` to my class definition. Could you please reply in an answer, so that I can acceppt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @Data is a short cut which includes @EqualsAndHashCode.  Try explicitly adding @EqualsAndHashCode and set `callSuper` to false.

However, for long-term maintenance, it may be safer to override equals/hashCode in the base class and just return true/0, or apply @EqualsAndHashCode to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

**So, why does the test fail? Is it a hashCode() problem due to the inheritence of AbstractName? How can I fix that?
BTW, it does not fail, if Name is a standalone class and not a subclass of AbstractName**

Elaborating regarding why the test would fail when callSuper is True.

Lets say you have a Child class which extends an abstract class. (or any other class for that matter)

Name.java:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Name extends AbstractName {
```

AbstractName.java:

```
public class AbstractName {
//some fields
```

Now, when we compare 2 instances of Name.java with same values then because we are overriding equals() and hashcode() methods using `@EqualsAndHashCode` lombok annotation in Name.java so the values are checked correctly. But since we are not overriding the equals() and hashcode() method in AbstractName.java so by default the equals() will always fail even if the values of properties are the same (unless the AbstractName's object instances are pointing to same object reference)

So, one option would be to make `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)` in the Child class. But then the fields in the parent class (AbstractName.java) will not be compared

Solution:- Better option would be to add `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)` in Name.java and `@EqualsAndHashCode` in AbstractName.java so that the equals() and hashcode() are overridden in both parent and child class so that the fields in all classes are compared correctly